# SQL Joining two tables creating auto increment for access

Tags: sql, ms-access, auto-increment

I am able to join two tables  DELIVERYDATE and DELIVERYTIME to create new table DELIVERYSLOT but I am unable to generate an new auto_increment ID(SlotNumber) in DELIVERYSLOT

DeliveryDate

```
12/16/2015
12/17/2015
12/18/2015
12/19/2015
```

DeliveryTime

```
10:00  - 12:00
12:00 - 14:00
14:00 - 16:00
8:00 - 10:00

 SELECT 
      DELIVERYDATE.DeliveryDate, DELIVERYTIME.DeliveryTime,
      SlotNumber 
 INTO DELIVERYSLOT 
 FROM DELIVERYDATE, DELIVERYTIME;
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In Access, you could design the DELIVERYSLOT table to include the auto-increment column (autoID, or whatever you want to call it) before entering any data into it, then run the query as an INSERT INTO.

When you run your join query, it should automatically add the autoID values for each new record entered from the query.

Or is there a reason you want to do it all in one SQL statement?

Comment: Wouldn't the Query overwrite whatever is in the DELIVERYLOT table including auto_number. Also how would I go about doing an INSERT INTO with a JOIN?